Pentesting Microsoft Dynamics Navision
I am currently pentesting a Microsoft Dynamics NAV ERP using their client (no web access).
Anyone has done this before and could share some tips?
My current findings are:

the File Data export function allows to export the whole database even using a standard profile. (Bad access control).
the user expiry date is not systematically set

I am kind a stuck with that for now. Any ideas for testing would be appreciated.
Thank you
tried to check user data access controls
data in transit is encrypted

Good luck, mate.
